# Бегущая строка с циклом while

Tags: python, while

Помогите написать бегущую строку на python в терминале
Пример:

> Введите вашу надпись:
>
> АВТОКАФЕ

вывод:

```
А
В
Т
О
К
А
Ф
Е
```

нужно это сделать с помощью цикла while

Comment: `print(*input(), sep = "\n")`

Answer (score 1):

чем вас фриланс.ру не устраивает?
там же качественнее, чем тут помогают

```
text = '...'

#бегущая строка
text = text[1:] + text[:1]
```

вот это основная часть бегущей строки

P.S.

хотя ваш пример говорит НЕ О БЕГУЩЕЙ СТРОКЕ, а о выводе строки в вертикальном виде

так?

если в примере вам еще и `while` нужен (т.е. совсем неоптимально делать), тогда

```
text = input()

while len(text) > 0:
    print(text[0])
    text = text[1:]
```

только это никакая не бегущая строка

Comment: спасибо, но мне именно интересно, как сделать это через while?

Comment: `while True:` дальше вызываете мой код дальше `print(text)` ну и внутри `while` надо задержку поставить `sleep(1)` к примеру